# Azure function with failover service bus connection string

Tags: .net, azure-functions, azureservicebus

How to design an Azure function with service bus trigger which has fail over connection strings.

My understanding of azure function service bus trigger is it will be triggered only by 1 service bus. How can I switch to failover connection string?

Example:
Service_bus_connection_string_1
Service_bus_connection_string_2

Comment: Fail over Connection String? What do you mean by this? Why does a connection string fail? Can you explain it clearly?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. The trigger only works with a single connection string today. Azure Service Bus DR only works with the Premium tier and even with that, failover is not automated.

Answer (score 0):

We cannot have Failover in Service bus and we have to use only either Primary or Secondary Connection string to connect to Azure Function as of today:

[image]

In Azure function :

[image]

After that click on save, Now you can use Con inside azure function.